# Pass function parameter directly to class variable

Tags: c++, function, struct, constructor

I have a class `lazy_segment_tree`. This is the current constructor

```
template<typename T>
struct lazy_segment_tree{
    int n;
    int H;
    T base;
    vector<T> segtree;
    vector<T> lazytree;
    T (*join)(T,T);
    T (*assign)(int,T,T);
    lazy_segment_tree(vector<T> &seq, T (*merge)(T,T), T (*create)(int, T,T), T defvalue){
        join=merge;
        assign=create;
        base=defvalue;
        n=seq.size();
    }
};
```

Can't I directly make the construction parameters go to the values in the class variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what do you mean by 'directly'.

But in this case you should use initializer list to initialize the member variables. More on initializer lists [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Applied to your code, the constructor would now look like this:

```
lazy_segment_tree(vector<T> &seq, T (*merge)(T,T), T (*create)(int, T,T), T defvalue)
    : join(merge)
    , assign(create)
    , base(defvalue)
    , n(seq.size())
{}
```

In your original code, all the members are first default-constructed during initialization of the class. Then, the body of the constructor is called where you use '=' to copy assign the constructor parameters.

When initializer list is used, the members are directly constructed with specified parameters.

Depending on what T might be, it may or may not make real difference. Nevertheless, initializer lists are the standard way to initialize class members and you should use it if possible.